# Сдвинуть элементы массива на k позиций

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм

Дан массив. Нужно сдвинуть циклично элементы этого массива на 2 позиции влево.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

пусть а - это массив для сдвига, а size_array - его размер и пусть массив будет целочисленный.

```
int tmp1, tmp2;
tmp1 = a[0];
tmp2 = a[1];
for (int i = 0; i < size_array-2; i++)
    a[i] = a[i+2];
a[size_array-2] = tmp1;
a[size_array-1] = tmp2;
```

если нужно сдвинуть на какое то другое кол-во позиций, то обычно применяют последовательный сдвиг.
Ещё можно завести массив, равный сдвигу, скопировать туда начальные элементы (memcpy) остальные элементы сдвинуть (memmove) и скопировать с дополнительно массива назад элементы в конец исходного массива.,

UPD:
[здесь](http://codelab.ru/task/cycle_shift/) есть очень интересные объяснения, как делать сдвиг.

Comment: я для таких целей использую функцию:
<pre>
int IndexNormalizer(int count, int index)
{
    return index >= 0
        ? index - count * (index / count) // + 
        : count + index + count * (-(index + 1) / count);//+
}
</pre>
теперь можно не бояться IndexOutOfRangeException

если элементов 7, а вы введёте 10 индекс, то функция преобразует его в 4, если -10 - в 5.

теперь операция
a[n] = b[n+-2] будет выполнима в любом случае.

Comment: а можно алгоритм обяснить на словах, а я уже сам попробую написать программу ?

Comment: ``A = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`` - исходный массив

возможные варианты сдвига:

``B = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1]``

для этого каждому i-му элементу массива B присваеваем каждый  нормализированый элемент массива A c индексом ``i+сдвиг``  

``B = [5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]``

а для этого каждый i-тый элемент массива A присваеваем каждому нормализированому элементу массива B с индексом ``i+сдвиг``

Answer (score 1):

В С++ для этого есть функция [`std::rotate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>

int main() {
    int arr[10] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    std::rotate(arr, arr+8, arr+10); // Перемещаем [arr, arr+8) в конец массива.

    int expected[10] = {8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
    assert(std::equal(arr, arr+10, expected)); // Должно получиться как в expected.
}
```

Пример реализации `rotate` из статьи на cppreference.com:

```
template <class ForwardIt>
void rotate(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt n_first, ForwardIt last)
{
    ForwardIt next = n_first;
    while (first != next) {
        std::iter_swap(first++, next++);
        if (next == last) {
            next = n_first;
        } else if (first == n_first) {
            n_first = next;
        }
    }
}
```

`std::iter_swap(a, b)` меняет местами содержимое итераторов, т.е. `swap(*a, *b)`.

Answer (score 0):

В библиотеке `Boost` как и в `std` присутствует `rotate`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    // перемещаем  1,2  в конец массива
    boost::range::rotate(vec, vec.begin() + 2);

    std::cout << "результат: ";
    boost::range::copy(vec, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Выведет: *результат: 3 4 5 1 2*

Официальная документация [тут](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/algorithms/mutating/rotate.html)

Исходник [тут](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/boost/range/algorithm/rotate.hpp)

Answer (score 0):

```
int tmp1 = a[0];
int tmp2 = a[1];
System.arraycopy(a, 2, a, 0, a.length - 2);
a[size_array-2] = tmp1;
a[size_array-1] = tmp2;
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.