# Как в масиве переместить элемент с одной позиций на другую?

Tags: c++, массивы

Есть массив:

```
18.666667
-9216.000000
-4480.000000
-2389.333333
-2016.000000
448.000000
```

Как переставить `18.6` на место между `-2016` и `448` (на предпоследнюю позицию)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сохранить 18.6 во временной переменной, сдвинуть все в массиве начиная с -9216... по -2016... включительно на один элемент, и поставить сохраненное значение в нужное место...

Comment: Возможно, это XY-проблема, и на самом-то деле автору надо просто отсортировать массив?

Comment: @Yaant  Возможно. Но я не Нострадамус. Сортировать и переместить элементы - совершенно разные задачи. Если нет четкого ТЗ - результат ХЗ :) А вдруг автору нужен циклический сдвиг? :)

Comment: Нет, все работает. Думал напишут код, по которому я бы сообразил, но и этого было достаточно. Сам набросал и вроде как работает. Спасибо.

Comment: `double tmp = a[0]; for(int i = 1; i <= 4; ++i) a[i-1]=a[i]; a[4] = tmp;` Теоретически можно применить `memmove`.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно создать новую переменную, в которую сохранить предпоследний элемент( иначе он пропадет). Дале устанавливаем  последний элемент вместо предпоследнего. А последний элемент равен той новой переменной.

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать сдвинуть элемент массива на k позиций с помощью метода [`std::rotate:`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) Более детально описано [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/486718/2110)

Answer (score 0):

Для арифметических типов проще всего и эффективнее будет воспользоваться стандартной функцией `std::memmove`, объявленной в заголовочном файле `<cstring>`.

Например,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    double a[] =
    {
        18.666667, -9216.000000, -4480.000000,
        -2389.333333, -2016.000000, 448.000000 
    };

    for (double x : a) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    size_t src = 0, dsn = 4;

    double tmp = a[src];
    std::memmove(a + src, a + src + 1, ( dsn - src) * sizeof( double ));
    a[dsn] = tmp;

    for (double x : a) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль

```
18.6667 -9216 -4480 -2389.33 -2016 448
-9216 -4480 -2389.33 -2016 18.6667 448
```

Answer (score -1):

```
std::sort(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));
std::sort(arr.begin() arr.end());
std::sort(pointer, pointer + arrsize);
```

В зависимости от типа используемого массива и версии стандарта.